# Change permissions for console user (MacOS)

Tags: bash, macos, scripting, permissions

I am trying to write a tiny script to change permissions for a specific folder for the logged in users on macbooks. None of these users have admin rights so I have to do run it remotely as root through our MDM.
I am not sure I am getting the syntax right. Can someone help me with this?

```
    #!/bin/sh
   # Get current logged in user
   TargetUser=$(echo "show State:/Users/ConsoleUser" | \
    scutil | awk '/Name :/ && ! /loginwindow/ { print $3 }')

   # Update permissions for target user
   chown -R "${TargetUser}" /usr/local/bin
   chmod g+w /usr/local/bin
```

Comment: Why do you think there is something wrong with this script?

Comment: Side note: it's generally bad security practice to give regular users write access to commands they execute.

Comment: A true `#!/bin/sh` won't support `var=$(cmdSub)`. Do you get an error message there? If you do, try `var=\`cmdSub\`` . Better to use `#!/bin/bash` if possible. Good luck.

Comment: And the first place to check is https://shellcheck.net . Good luck.